# Transaction - Querying database management

Tags: oracle, mongodb, transactions, etl, talend

Could someone give me advices about managing transaction-querying in relational database. Concretely, I have a Oracle database with 10000k records (1TB). In context of a job ETL (Talend), I have to get all these data from Oracle database, process them and insert them into an NoSQL database (MongoDB)

Supposing due to some technical reason (network,...), my server is suspended after the 9999th record inserted.

The question is: how can I continue at the 100000th record in the Oracle database but not drop all previous results.

Thanks!

Comment: Add a "processed" flag/column to your source table, and set to Y or 1 or something to indicate it is processed as part of the transaction.  add constraint on your ETL query to exclude records that are processed.

Comment: Thank OldProgrammer, but in my select there are at least 4 inner join, in this case, I can not add the "processed" flag!

Comment: OK, since you do not should specific table details, can't provide more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the source table ordered by some column, preferable unique one.

```
select ... from SOURCE order by ID;
```

If the column is unique, on restart simple check the highest value in the TARGET database and restart with values higher (>) than this value.

```
select ... from SOURCE where ID > {max ID from TARGET} order by ID;
```

If the column in not unique you must restart with values higher or equal this value (>=) and additionally remove the duplicated records that could by introduced this way.